# how can I "simulate" the lead assignment rules to understand which user an existing lead would be assigned too if I ran it back through the LARs?

Tags: apex, assignment-rules, lead-assignment

We are building a screenflow that we want to display the user a lead would go to should the proceed to the next screen. Figured this would be a apex action, but I can't seem to find anything about a class like this existing. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a practical way to simulate lead assignment rules. Instead, perform the assignment, query the data back to see the results, then roll back the transaction. In Apex:

```
public class GetLeadAssignmentResult {
  public class Input {
    @InvocableVariable public Lead lead;
    @InvocableVariable public Id assignmentId;
  }
  public class Output {
    @InvocableVariable public Id ownerIdResult;
  }
  @InvocableMethod(label='Test Lead Assignment' description='Test Lead Assignment')
  public static Output[] simulateAssignment(Input[] inputs) {
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();
    Lead[] leads = new Lead[0];
    for(Input item: inputs) {
      Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
      dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= true;
      Lead testLead = new Lead(id=item.lead.Id);
      if(item.assignmentId != null) {
        dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId = item.assignmentId;
      } else {
        dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
      }
      testLead.setOptions(dmo);
      leads.add(testLead);
    }
    update leads;
    Map<Id, Lead> leadResults = new Map<Id, Lead>(
      [SELECT OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leads]
    );
    Database.rollback(sp);
    Output[] outputs = new Output[0];
    for(Input item: inputs) {
      Output result = new Output();
      result.ownerIdResult = leadResults.get(item.lead.Id);
      outputs.add(result);
    }
    return outputs;
  }
}
```

Here, we first take the leads we want to simulate assignment for, set a save point, perform the DML operation, get the results of that operation, roll back the actual database transaction, then gather the results and return that data to the flow.

This only works on previously existing leads. You'll need to modify this if you need to simulate leads not yet created, if you expect you may get validation errors, etc.

Comment: Wow! thanks for the quick answer!